# Sum of custom value from 2 custom fields

Tags: wordpress

Im making code like this.

If custom field price1 exists, set it into $total-price.
Else if cusotm field price2 exists, set it into $total-price.

Then caculate sum of $total-price.

I made this code, but 0 returned.

```
<?php $my_posts = get_posts( $args );
$sum = 0;
foreach($my_posts as $p) {
if(post_custom('price1')){
$total-price[] = get_post_meta( $p->ID, 'price1', true );} 
elseif(post_custom('price2')){
$total-price[] = get_post_meta( $p->ID, 'price2', true );}
$sum  += $total-price;
}
echo number_format($total-price);
?>
```

Somebody knows what is wrong with my code?

I made this code following advise below.

```
    <?php 
    // Get Post Object(s)
    $my_posts = get_posts( $args );
    // Initial Price is Zero.
    $sum = 0;
    // Loop each Post
    foreach($my_posts as $post) {
        // Fetch Custom Fields
        $price1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'price1', true );
        $price2 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'price2', true );
        // Set Total Price to price1 if its set
        if(!empty($price1) && is_numeric($price1)) {
            $total_price = $price1;
        }
        // Change to price 2 if it exists
        if(!empty($price2) && is_numeric($price2)) {
            $total_price = $price2;
        }
    $sum +=$total_price;   
 }
    // Use $total_price as you want
    echo number_format($sum);
```

Now, $total_price shows something strange.  I set only 1 meta like 200 to $price1, and then $sum becomes 600.  When I delete 200, then it returns 0.

I like above simple code.  Somebody knows why sum of total price become strange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your code, please know that you are trying to subtract array push from number here : `$total-price[]`, it is invalid syntax and will result in errors. Things apart, here is the right way to check for custom fields and condition total price accordingly. Comments are self explanatory :

```
<?php 
// Get Post Object(s)
$my_posts = get_posts( $args );
// Loop each Post
foreach($my_posts as $post) {
    // Initial Price is Zero.
    $total_price = 0;
    // Fetch Custom Fields
    $price1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'price1', true );
    $price2 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'price2', true );
    // Set Total Price to price1 if its set
    if(!empty($price1) && is_numeric($price1)) {
        $total_price = $price1;
    }
    // Change to price 2 if it exists
    if(!empty($price2) && is_numeric($price2)) {
        $total_price = $price2;
    }
    // Use $total_price as you want 
    echo number_format($total_price );
}
```

// Out of Post loop

Comment: Thank you for your great help.  I think this is very close to code I wanted.  I only need to sum total price.  Should I set $sum=0 instead of $total_price, and $sum +=$total_price?  If you know something smart code, it would be much appreciated to hear!  @Maulik Parmar

Comment: My bad, you need to move $sum & echo statement inside for loop if you want to process this for single post, depending on template you are, $posts array may have more than one post objects, so branch your logic accordingly, I have updated code to reflect local calculation in answer.